# iTunes Connect yellow button

Tags: app-store-connect

This is probably a silly question, but I can't find the answer anywhere.  When there's the yellow button next to an app I've submitted to iTunes Connect, it means they're still reviewing it, right?

How long does that review process take?  I think it's been yellow for about two weeks now, does that fit the timeline?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yellow means that it's either:

- In review
- Waiting for review
- Waiting for binary upload
- waiting for export compliance

Basically anything that needs you to wait and be patient.

the review process takes time, anywhere from 1 week to 1 month depending on your luck and how complex the app is.

Answer (score 0):

After submitting your app, Yellow means one of the following:

-In review
-Waiting for review

An average timeline for an app to be reviews fits from a week, to two weeks. It should definitely not take any longer than 3 weeks at most. Make sure that you selected the "Submit for Review" button in iTunes connect as uploading your build (project) to iTunes connect will not automatically submit it for review. Just be patient, and as long as you followed my directions above you should get a response soon.